# How to get mouse movement while dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mousemove

How can I get the current position of the mouse while dragging over an element with `AllowDrop = false`? I need the current mouse position because I want my adorner to follow my mouse while dragging.

The `DragOver` event doesn't work since it only fires when dragging above an element with `AllowDrop = true`.

**EDIT:**

Some Context: I have an `ItemsControl` and want to drag & drop the items to reorder them. Reordering works, however my adorner doesn't follow the mouse.

Comment: Set a `bool _isDragging` to `true` while you're dragging, and do stuff in MouseMove.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: The MouseMove event doesn't fire while dragging, unfortunately.

Comment: @gartenriese Did you find any solution?

Comment: I found this package works great https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook

Comment: @camino: I'm not sure, it was a long time ago. I think I listened to the PreviewDragOver event and got the mouse position from the DragEventArgs like this: `e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender)`.

Comment: @camino: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094448/how-to-update-the-position-of-a-drag-adorner-during-wpf-drag-n-drop?rq=1), maybe that has a good answer, it looks similar to what I did.

Comment: @gartenriese I will give a try, thanks!